# What is the difference between the different awk versions?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, awk

I am reading through awk [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) but I am just wondering about the awk versions as I have encountered issues before with different awks. Below is a look at the different version I have. As I understand it there is awk, mawk and gawk. With gawk being the newest/better. **Can anyone clarify my assumptions?** I s GNU Awk 4.1.1 the newest and best to be using i.e. is it gawk? Any other comments on the different versions?

env1 - cygwin on my pc

```
$ awk -Wversion 2>/dev/null || awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 6.0.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2014 Free Software Foundation.
```

env2 - a docker container

```
$ awk -Wversion 2>/dev/null || awk --version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan
```

Comment: "Newest"? They're developed in parallel.

Comment: I suggest moving this question to [so] or [unix.se], where more awk specialists reside.

Comment: posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409632/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-awk-versions) what should be posted at superuser?